# Date Formatting In dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-date-ranger directive

Tags: datetime-format

I am using [Dalelotts angular bootstrap date range picker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Which gives the date and time in the format as `Thu Mar 09 2017 06:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` .But I need the date format to be in `2017-03-09 06:30:00`.How can I make this.Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Date range picker html code

```
<div class="dropdown form-group">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownStart" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"
       href="#">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateRangeStart">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed' }"
                        data-on-set-time="startDateOnSetTime()"
                        data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($dates)"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown form-group">
    <label>End Date</label>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownEnd" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"
       href="#">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateRangeEnd">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeEnd"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownEnd', renderOn: 'start-date-changed' }"
                        data-on-set-time="endDateOnSetTime()"
                        data-before-render="endDateBeforeRender($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate)"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my controller

```
$scope.endDateBeforeRender = endDateBeforeRender
$scope.endDateOnSetTime = endDateOnSetTime
$scope.startDateBeforeRender = startDateBeforeRender
$scope.startDateOnSetTime = startDateOnSetTime

function startDateOnSetTime () {
  $scope.$broadcast('start-date-changed');
}

function endDateOnSetTime () {
  $scope.$broadcast('end-date-changed');
}

function startDateBeforeRender ($dates) {
  if ($scope.dateRangeEnd) {
    var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeEnd);

    $dates.filter(function (date) {
      return date.localDateValue() >= activeDate.valueOf()
    }).forEach(function (date) {
      date.selectable = false;
    })
  }
}

function endDateBeforeRender ($view, $dates) {
  if ($scope.dateRangeStart) {
    var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeStart).subtract(1, $view).add(1, 'minute');

    $dates.filter(function (date) {
      return date.localDateValue() <= activeDate.valueOf()
    }).forEach(function (date) {
      date.selectable = false;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Somebody help me please

Comment: Anybody knows the answer . Its getting worst

Answer (score 1):

Add **`data-date-time-input`** attribute into the input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-time-input="YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss" data-ng-model="dateRangeStart">
```